# Delphi 10 Seattle vs API cloudflare.com

Tags: delphi, api, cloudflare

Опыт работы с cloudflare.com есть, паркую через их api домены, теперь возникла такая проблема, js и css файлы кэшируются на стороне cloudflare чтобы очистить кэш нужно зайти в панельку, выбрать домен и там нажать на кнопочку, всё очень просто если домен 1 или штук 5, но их у меня немного больше и это занимает достаточно много времени... В общем я сразу же пошёл смотреть инструкцию к их api, их оригинальное описание что нужно сделать чтобы очистить кэш:

```
 curl -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/purge_cache" \
 -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
 -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data '{"purge_everything":true}'
```

`023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353` - это id конкретного домена, который я получаю путём того же api без проблем

На Delphi мой код выглядит вот так:

```
        idhttp:=Tidhttp.Create(nil);
        SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
        SSL.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvTLSv1;
        SSL.SSLOptions.Mode:= sslmUnassigned;
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
        idhttp.AllowCookies := true;
        idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-Auth-Email: My_email');
        idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-Auth-Key: My_Auth_key');
        idhttp.Request.ContentType:='application/json';

        memory:=TStringStream.Create(); 
        memory.WriteString('{"purge_everything":true}');
        memory.Encoding.UTF8;
        try
        idhttp.Delete('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/purge_cache',memory);
        except  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
            begin
                s:=E.ErrorMessage;
            end;
        end;
       Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
```

В ответ получаю сообщение об ошибке вот такое:

```
{"success":false,"errors":[{"code":1012,"message":"Request must contain one of \"purge_everything\", \"files\", \"tags\", or \"hosts\""}],"messages":[],"result":null}
```

Оно мне говорит "Request must contain one of" вы должны передать любой один параметр из перечисленных далее...

Так я же передаю данные, точно так же как и в предыдущих задачах, меняются только отправляемые данные ну и метод отправки до этого был `POST`, а тут по инструкции требует метод `DELETE`

Всё сделано по инструкции что ему надо не знаю... Вот ссылка на страницу описания api к моей задачи:
  `https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-all-files`

Comment: `memory.Encoding.UTF8` - эта строка де-факто не делает ничего. Попробуйте создать поток с указанием кодировки: `memory:=TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не знал что строка `memory.Encoding.UTF8` не имеет значения, хотя без неё предыдущие запросы не работали, убрал её, написал как вы сказали, ошибка осталась, та же самая

Comment: странно, что работали :) В любом случае - сейчас строковый поток у вас создается правильно - с указанием используемой кодировки. Проблема только в том, что (по крайней мере в версии Indy, идущей в комплекте с Delphi 10.1) метод Delete вторым параметром ждет A*Response*Content. Т.е. это выходной параметр. Получается, что всё, записанное в него вами не имеет значения. Кстати, то же самое и со штатным System.Net.THTTPClient - метод Delete не принимает входные параметры. Можно попробовать симитировать их, как в https://stackoverflow.com/a/21004441/4908529

Comment: Не получается ничего... Почему он не видит данные которые я отправляю методом `DELETE`